# tuning heap size in Neo4J

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm new to Neo4J and I'm getting my hands dirty on windows 7 and Neo4J version 3.0.3
I was reading the chapter about tuning in Neo4J documentation.
In this chapter, under the heap sizing section is written:

> The heap memory size is determined by the parameters in
>   `NEO4J_HOME/conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf`, namely
>   `dbms.memory.heap.initial_size` and `dbms.memory.heap.max_size` providing
>   the heap size in Megabytes, e.g. 16000. It is recommended to set these
>   two parameters to the same value to avoid unwanted full garbage
>   collection pauses.

I tried to search for `neo4j-wrapper.conf` file but I didn't find it, nor did I find `conf` folder.

Should I create a conf folder and place a file named neo4j-wrapper.conf inside of it?
Where should `conf` folder be placed?

Will neo4j-wrapper.conf contain only these 2 rows?

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size = 16000
dbms.memory.heap.max_size = 16000
```